# Java - JSPF Error

Tags: java

I'm using the [JSPF](https://code.google.com/p/jspf/) framework for my Java plugin system. I'm getting this error:

```
Adding plugins in 'raw' classpaths, such as 'bin/' or 'classes/' is not recommended. Please use classpath://* instead (the video is a bit outdated in this respect).
```

**IPlugin.java**

```
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.Plugin;

public interface IPlugin extends Plugin {
    public String handleStuff();
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.annotations.PluginImplementation;

@PluginImplementation
public class Test implements IPlugin {
    public String handleStuff() {
        return ("Swag");
    }
}
```

**Testing.java/Main class**

```
import java.io.File;

import net.xeoh.plugins.base.PluginManager;
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.impl.PluginManagerFactory;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PluginManager pm = PluginManagerFactory.createPluginManager();
        pm.addPluginsFrom(new File("bin/").toURI());

        IPlugin cool = pm.getPlugin(IPlugin.class);
        cool.handleStuff();
    }

}
```

Please help me

Comment: Did you even read the error, and look at your code?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand it. I understand that it's not good in bin but where can i put it?

Comment: You could try something like this... pm.addPluginsFrom(new File("plugins/").toURI()); and put your plugins in plugins dir